# How to put subscript on a letter

Tags: math-mode

[image]How can I write a letter with a character above and under it?For example a V with 1 above and 0 under?

Thank you!

Comment: @egreg: my mistake, removed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should write:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\overset{1}{\underset{0}{V}}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: I mean on the the op the letter and under the letter shoudl be those numbers

Comment: I post a photo to understand better what I want to do :)

Comment: @CarmenMitru sorry, see my edit ;-)